# spring beans annotations not working

Tags: spring, annotations

I've read that in order to use annotations to configure spring beans, i've to configure my web.xml like the following:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
    <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>com.test.MainConfiguration</param-value>   
</context-param>
```

But it can't find the class, and gives the error:

> GRAVE: Exception while loading the app
>   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load configuration class: com.test.MainConfiguration

Thanks to AngerClown, i replaced:

```
com.test.MainConfiguration
```

with classpath:

```
classpath:com.test.MainConfiguration
```

and tested also

```
classpath:com/test/MainConfiguration
```

but now i get the exception:

```
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: name
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath$Loader.getResource(URLClassPath.java:495)
        at sun.misc.URLClassPath.getResource(URLClassPath.java:169)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:194)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.APIClassLoaderServiceImpl$APIClassLoader.loadClass(APIClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:174)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:296)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
        at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1415)
        at org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext.java:90)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:465)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:395)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:4664)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:535)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5266)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:499)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:912)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:694)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1947)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1619)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:90)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:126)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:241)
        at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:236)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:339)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:183)
        at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:272)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:305)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:320)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1176)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$900(CommandRunnerImpl.java:83)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1235)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1224)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:365)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:204)
        at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:166)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:245)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
        at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
        at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
        at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
        at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
        at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: Error message says `com.test.MainConfiguration`, whereas `web.xml` says `MyConfigurationClass`. Is this correct?

Comment: no sorry, i modified businness names to anonymous before posting to stackoverflow. actually they are the same and correct. I'm correcting the question.

Comment: Can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: The `classpath:` syntax is not appropriate here, you were right the first time. You need to find out why it fails to load `com.test.MainConfiguration`, there should be some other clue in the log somewhere.

Answer (score -1):

`contextConfigLocation` is supposed to be a file system / classpath location, not a classname. If com.test.MainConfiguration is supposed to be a file in the classpath, you need to use the "classpath:" syntax like this: `classpath:com.test.MainConfiguration`.

Comment: It's not correct, see http://blog.springsource.com/2008/03/26/spring-java-configuration-whats-new-in-m3/

Comment: Not true.  The meaning of `contextConfigLocation` depends on the context class, and `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` expects it to be a fully-qualified class name, not a resource location.

Comment: Oops. I didn't realize that. Spring is the framework that keeps on giving :)